# How to get the value of a non-type template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

Here is the example:

```
template <int n>
class A { };

class B {
public:
  int foo() {
    return a.n;  // error
  }
private:
  A<10> a;
};
```

I want to get the value of instantiated class `A<10>`'s non-type template parameter in class `B` other than template `A` itself, is there a way to do this? Or should I use some other designs to avoid this problem?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ But `B` is a normal class without member named `n`.

Comment: You declared `A<10> a`, 10 being a compile-time constant. So if it's a constant, why not just hardcode number 10 in `foo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't get the type to cooperate (by publishing the parameter value), you can extract it yourself with a traits class:

```
template<class> struct A_param; // not defined

template<int N> struct A_param<A<N>> {
    static constexpr int value = N;
};

// a more general implementation would probably want to handle cv-qualified As etc.
```

Then use `A_param<decltype(a)>::value`.

Answer (score 6):

You can't access other classes template parameters just like that. The other class has to expose it, for instance:

```
template <int n>
class A {
public:
    static const int num = n;
};
```

Then you can access it as `a.num` (or `A<10>::num` of course)

Answer (score 3):

If you have a member `A<10>` your class B already know about the template parameter. Use that value instead. If the template parameter is indeed not named, let A define a member that reflects the template parameter.

1 -

```
class B {
public:
  int foo() {
    return n;  
  }
private:
  const int n = 10;
  A<n> a;
};
```

2 -

```
template <int n>
class A { 
public:
    static const int template_param = n;
};
```

Comment: Can I use `decltype` or something like compile time type identification to solve this problem?

Comment: @Jaege What is the exact problem you want to solve? Decltype can't access the template parameter. When the class is created from the template the A<X> is just the class name.  If you need access to the template parameter at runtime a constant is the way to go.

Comment: I was doing the exercise 16.14 in *C++ Primer*, in which a class template `Screen` and a class `Window_mgr` were defined. Inside `Window_mgr::clear()`, I need to clean the contents of the screen. Complete code is [here](https://ideone.com/6N8z7w).